# Can't find Spring Data Rest Endpoint with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I am trying out Spring Data Rest for the first time, but I can't seem to find my repository endpoint at `localhost:8080/books`  Does anyone see what I configured wrong?

Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {Book.class})
public class SpringDataMicroServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringDataMicroServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Book Entity

```
@lombok.Getter
@lombok.Setter
@lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor
@lombok.EqualsAndHashCode(of = "isbn")
@lombok.ToString(exclude="id")
@Entity
public class Book implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String isbn;

    private String title;

    private String author;

    private String description;
}
```

BookRepository

```
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {
}
```

Gradle Build file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.4.RELEASE'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'io.spring.platform:platform-bom:2.0.5.RELEASE'
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
    compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-hal-browser')
    compile('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.6')
    compile('org.springframework.retry:spring-retry')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-ws')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator')

    runtime('com.h2database:h2')

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
    testCompile('org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc')
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In spring boot , by default you don't need to do `@ComponentScan` , `@EntityScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories` . Add `@RepositoryRestResource` to your repository . Remove all annotations from the starter class except `@SpringBootApplication` . Spring boot will scan all packages by default . You will be then able to find the endpoint `localhost:8080/books`. It didn't work for you because you were specifically scanning only the entity class . The repository was not scanned . When you remove those annotations , all packages will be scanned and repository beans will we crated and the endpoints will be available.

If you are using multiple packages make sure to keep your application launcher in the base package.  Example:

```
src
    main
        java
            com.myapp.springstuff
                Application.java
                package1
                package2
```

Comment: Interesting I will definitely try that it would be nice to cut down on the annotations if Spring Boot will locate everything.  Can't wait to test this.

Comment: Did you try it out?

Comment: After some tests looks like I definitely need the annotations.  Currently I have a package spread with application  and domain.  Without these 3 annotations I don't load any endpoints regarding book.  It looks like I can remove the component scan, but if I remove either the repository or the JpaRepositories I have problems.

Comment: I have a working project with Spring Boot 1.3.5 , spring data rest and Hsqldb . I have only used @SpringBootApplication . Everything works fine.

Comment: hmm strange. multiple packages?

Comment: Yes , multiple packages . Can you share the project

Comment: Sure here you go: https://github.com/Mandalorian007/SpringDataMicroService

Comment: I just moved the starter class to root and removed the annotations . Usually the starter class will be in the root . Everything is working fine

Answer (score 4):

Ok fixed it all I needed to do was add some annotations for scanning on my main application.  I had to tell it to find the entities and repositories since they were in a different package.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {BookRepository.class})
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {Book.class})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {BookRepository.class})
public class SpringDataMicroServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringDataMicroServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're missing a resource controller (`@RestController`) that routes `GET` requests for `/books` (`@RequestMapping("/books")`) to a Java method that will retrieve a `Book` entity from a database, for example.

See *Create a resource controller* [here for more details](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/).

Comment: I am using Spring Data Rest it will generate the rest controller based off of my entity model.  However, it looks like I have my configuration wrong somewhere.

Comment: You're right @MatthewFontana, looking at the example here there is no controller: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-book